# Gram-Schmidt map as a Riemannian submersion

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

We equip $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathrm{O}(n)$ with their left-invariant metrics, whose restrictions to the corresponding neutral elements  is the standard inner product $\mathrm{Trace}(AB^{\mathrm{tr}})$ of  $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Let  $f:\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})\to  \mathrm{O}(n)$ be the  Gram-Schmidt map. This  map  is  uniquely defined via [Gram-schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#The_Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) which is  applied to the  columns of  a  matrix.

> Is $f$ a Riemannian submersion  with respect to these Riemannian structures? If the answer is negative, can  we change the  Riemannian metrics of these  spaces (not necessarily invariant  under group operations) to have $f$ as a Riemannian submersion?

Comment: Would you say more precisely what you call Gram-Schmidt map? And also say what you call a "partial isometry" between Riemannian manifolds?

Comment: @YCor  We  apply Gram-Schmidt method on the columns of  a  matrix $A$  in $Gl(n,\mathbb{R}$ so we obtain an  orthonormal base of  vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. They make  an orthonormal  matrix $f(A)\in O(n)$.

Comment: A  partial isometry is somehow a  linear  concept. a  linear map $Df:H_1 \to H_2$ is  a  partial isometry if it is an isometry between $({\ker Df}) ^{\perp}$  and $H_2$ where $H_i$'s are inner product spaces.  so  in the  Riemannian context we  consider the  corresponding tangent spaces.

Comment: @YCor  BTW thanks  for  your  revising my question.

Comment: @YCor  I just realize that the correct terminology is "Riemannian  submersion". So I revise the question.

Comment: You can perform Gram-Schmidt in a large number of ways that produce distinct maps $f$.

Comment: @RyanBudney  I think it is unique, I mean the following process  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram–Schmidt_process

Comment: @RyanBudney If we do not count this process as a unique well defined map, then how can we prove $O(n)$ is a (deformation) retract of $GL(n,\mathbb{R}$? So this process is a well defined map.

Comment: As in any situation.  If there is one deformation retraction of a space $X$ onto a subspace $A$, then there invariably is infinitely many distinct deformation-retractions.

Comment: For example, with Gram-Schmidt one feature lacking in the undergraduate textbook versions so often seen is that they aren't equivariant with respect to the permutation action of column vectors.  But it can be done equivariantly.

Comment: @RyanBudney  In my question I consider the  canonical one. But what is an equivariant version?

Comment: I forget how people do the equivalent version in general, but this should work: take the simplest step of Gram-Schmidt where you slide the n-th vector into the orthogonal complement of the span of the first (n-1)-vectors.  Think of that process as the solution to an ODE.  Average the ODE over the $\Sigma_n$-action, and take the solution to that equivariant ODE.  That should be the equivariant gram-schmidt.

Comment: @RyanBudney  Thank  you  for  this interesting  equivariant version.

Comment: @RyanBudney  To  be  honest I can not imagine existence of  such  an  equivariant processes. In  particular  what  is the restriction of  your  equivariant map  to  $O(n) \subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ ?Is  not reasonable  to expect every possible  Gram schmidt process restrict  to  identity on orthonormal group?I  confess that I  do not understand  the sketch of  equivariant process you mentioned. May you elaborate it or  give  a  reference? However existence of  such an equivariant map is  very interesting, if there exist any.

Comment: The ODE is zero on $O(n)$.  If you think of your matrix $A \in GL(n, \mathbb R)$ as $n$ column vectors $\vec v_1, \cdots, \vec v_n$ then I suppose the ODE would be $\frac{\partial  \vec v_i}{\partial t} = -proj_{\vec v_1, \cdots, \vec v_{i-1}, \vec v_{i+1}, \cdots, \vec v_n}(\vec v_i)$.   This ODE has exponential decay, so you have to extend time to $+\infty$ to get Gram-Schmidt.   I suspect there is a way to get a closed-form solution to this ODE, let me think about it for a second.

Comment: Here is a slightly different ODE that behaves similarly -- in particular it's got a cute matrix-level description $A' = A(I-A^TA)$.  Here $A \in GL(n,\mathbb R)$. A nice feature of this ODE is $O(n)$ is precisely the fixed-point set.

Comment: That last ODE is perhaps be most pleasant.  If you diagonalize $A^TA$ over the orthogonal group, it gives you a change of coordinates where you can write down a closed-form solution.  It decays exponentially to an equivariant Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: @RyanBudney  thank  you  for  elaboration  and the  precise  ODE $A'=A(I-A^TA)$. some  questions; is it  obvious  that $GL(n,\mathbb{R}$ is invariant under the  flow? But  My  main  question: What  do  you  mean  by  equivariant  Gram  schmidt  map? do  you  mean a  map  $f;GL(n,\mathbb{R}) \to O(n)$ which is  constant(fixed) on each orbit of  $\Sigma_n$ action? If it is the case, how  any  such a map can be restrict to  Identity on O(n)?

Comment: The thing I'm calling equivariant Gram-Schmidt is the function $f$ that sends a matrix $A$ to its limit as $t \to \infty$ under the solution to the ODE $A' = A(I-A^TA)$.  This ODE is (as time increases) complete, my initial way of seeing that is by using a canonical form to find a closed-form solution.  Precisely, if $A$ satisfies the above ODE, the matrix $A^TA$ satisfies the ODE $(A^TA)' = 2A^TA(I-A^TA)$, so this ode reduces to $y'=2y(1-y)$ i.e. it reduces to an ODE in the eigenvalues of $A^TA$. Since all the eigenvalues are positive, they converge to $1$, i.e. you get an orthogonal matirx.

Comment: @RyanBudney  So  by  equivariant  you  mean  an  equivariant  map  $f:GL(n,\mathbb{R})\to  O(n)$  via  the  obvious  action $\Sigma_n$ on  both  $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$  and  $O(n)$. Yes? So that is a  very interesting  construction.However it  lacks the  invariance the  span  of  First  k columns, for  each k.Yes? any  way it  would  be  possible that the answer to the  main post is  negative for  the canonical Gram Schmidt map, but the  answer would  be  affirmative for  the  map  you mentioned.What do you think about this?